# If all my variables' first difference is stationary, does it mean my variables are all stationary?

Tags: regression, stata

I wonder all my variables' first difference is stationary, does it mean my variables are all stationary in time series? What model should I use then? what the format would be? How to address this question in Stata?

Comment: Nope. Consider the time series $X_t=t$ as a counterexample.

Comment: Welcome to CV Nikita!

Answer (score 1):

**I wonder all my variables' first difference is stationary, does it mean my variables are all stationary in time series?**

No. For example, if $y_t = \beta y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t}$, where $|\beta| \ge 1$, and $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ then $y$ is a non-stationary process, however $\Delta y_{t} = y_t - y_{t-1}$ (the first difference of $y$) **is** stationary, because $\Delta y_{t} = \varepsilon_{t}$, and $\varepsilon$ is strongly stationary. (If $0 < |\beta| < 1$ in the simple model here, $y$ is said to be 'weakly stationary'.)

**What model should I use then?**

This depends on what your research question is. In general, if one can find stationary differences of time series data, one has options for modeling and inference which will not run afoul of spurious correlation. (Albeit, selection bias, and confounding via backdoor paths may still be involved.)

**what would the format would be?**

Not sure what you are asking here? The data would generally be organized in a unit-period format.

**How to address this question in Stata?**

Depends on what you want to do. Maybe read the help files for `tsset`, `xtset`, `xtunitroot`, `xtmixed`, and `tsvarlist`? One can *certainly* do a lot with time series models in Stata.

Comment: A major problem potentially is if some of your variables are stationary and some not, that is integrated of a different order. A lot of time series won't handle that. Think about this way, some variables may be changing and some not.

Comment: @user54285 Yep. That said, there are some models that acommodate non-stationarity (and weak stationarity) of the same order or less as the regressand (e.g., generalized error correction model based on the stationary first difference of $y$ is agnostic as to whether $x$ is stationary, or only its first difference is stationary… the cost is added modeling parameters, and the need to dolinear and nonlinear combinations to interpret).

Comment: @user54285 Not sure if you saw something in my answer that suggests I disagree with your comment, but "It depends" is a critically important caveat. :D

Comment: I am not commenting on your point, just making my own. I suspect you know a lot more than I on this topic. ARDL was the only time series regression I knew of that allowed the variables to be integrated of a different order. I have read comments by some that argue that it makes no substantive sense to look at a correlation between variables that are stationary to a non-stationary variable.